# Dropwizard JWT workflow

Tags: java, jwt, dropwizard

Design pattern help:

I have a dropwizard application that implements JWT for authentication. I have this working in the most basic form.

I have a User class which has all sorts of details about a user (email, name, settings etc)

However I've been advised that when I authenticate the user I should be returning a Principal rather than the actual user. Here is my method that does this:

```
@Override
public Optional<Principal> authenticate(JsonWebToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

    final User user = userCollection.findOneById(token.claim().subject());

    Principal principal = new Principal() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return user.getUsername();
        }
    };

    return Optional.of(principal);
}
```

I have the users stored in a mongoDB collection, so using the ID from the token I can retrieve that specific user and assign that users name to a new principal object and return that principal.

This means in my endpoints that require authentication, I can use properties from that Principal for example:

```
@POST
@Path("project-create")
public Response setProject(@Auth Principal principal, @Valid Project project) {
    [...]
    project.setAuthorName(principal.getName());
    [...]
}
```

This is all working, but what if I wanted to access other properties of the user which don't exist on the Principal?

Should I be using the `name` value of the principal to lookup the user in the database and retrieve that user each time I want to use one of the users properties?

Is there a massive flaw in what I've done? I don't have much experience on this front and find it hard to find real world examples around this.

Would appreciate some guidance around what sort of pattern/workflow I should be following.

Comment: You know you can make a subclass of `Principal` and use _that_. If you made `User` extend `Principal`, you could use that.

Comment: Just to clarify; I make an abstract class that implements Principal, I can then tell User to extend MyPrincipal, and then in my Authenticator class I can switch out all the principal objects for that of User?

Comment: Sure... make sure you switch out all the generic type parameters to User instead of Principal

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but then I get a compile error with the JWTAuthFilter not liking implements Authenticator<JsonWebToken, User>  not being a Principal, even though User is extending from Principal

Comment: Where did you get this `JWTAuthFilter` from?

Comment: I agree, hence my confusion around it all! I'm using this plugin here: https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt

Comment: Looking at the source I imagine you can do something like `new JWTAuthFilter.Builder<User>().setAuthenticator(...).setEverythingElse(..).buildAuthFilter()`

Comment: You are of course correct. What I was missing was ```User``` in Builder generics. If you want to write an answer I'll happily accept. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Authenticator` generic type is `Athenticator<C, P extends Principal>`, so you can make your `User` implement `Principal` and make your `Authenticator` something like

```
public class JWTAuthenicator extends Authenticator<JsonWebToken, User> {
    @Override
    public Optional<User> authenticate(JsonWebToken token) {}
}
```

Then build the `JWTAuthFilter` with the `User` generic type argument

```
new JWTAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
    .setAuthenticator(new JWTAuthenticator())
    .setEverythingElse(...)
    .buildAuthFilter();
```

Comment: I may have spoken a bit soon, while the authentication process works and passes, the value of @Auth User user is now always null even when return Optional.of(user) successfully returns the object. I'm not sure if this is to JWTFilter or Dropwizard

Comment: Did you register the DW AuthValueFactoryProvider?

Comment: I did, however it was still referencing Principal rather than User... Surely enough that fixed it. Slowly starting to understand now how this all hangs together!  Cheers again